# how to remove data from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

on the below code data.size() is equal to 6 and i'm sure the "if" block inside it should be execute at last 3 times,but it's execute once,why??

```
 private void deletePost(){

    byte count=0;
    Log.v(TAG,"size "+data.size());
    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        if(data.get(i).isItemSelected()){
            data.remove(i);
        //    deleteFromCloud(data.get(i).getId());
            Log.v(TAG,"POS "+i);
            count++;
        }
        Log.v(TAG,"i  "+i);

    }
    Log.v(TAG,"items deleted "+count);
    rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(this,count + " " + getString(R.string.itemsDeleted),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: If you remove the current item, all the following items will be shifted, i.e. you might skip items because of this. Try doing it from the end instead. for (int i = data.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: Iterate the list in reverse.

Comment: Your title seems to have little to do with your actual problem... I'd suggest rephrasing.

Comment: You can use iterator to remove elements from ArrayList while iterating on it. `Iterator<Data> iterator = data.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Data data = iterator.next();
    if (data.get(i).isItemSelected()) {
        data.remove(i);
        //    deleteFromCloud(data.get(i).getId());
        Log.v(TAG, "POS " + i);
        count++;
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "i  " + i);
}`

Comment: @amirdt This one `import java.util.Iterator;`